# I am trying to use a webhook to access a private google sheet file

Tags: google-sheets, webhooks, slack

I am trying to use a outgoing slack webhook to access a private google sheet file

Comment: I am trying to understand what your question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would advise against using an [outgoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks). Its an old and outdated approach and I would recommend to use either a [slash command](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/slash-commands) or the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api).

Second, you can access a google sheet using [Google's Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/). But you will need a script / Slack app to implement your logic and translate data between Slack and your Google sheet.